# DAX problem, filter/relation is ignored when I use IF in the RETURN clause

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm getting an unexpected result when I use an IF in the RETURN clause of a DAX expression. If I don't use the IF, but instead just a variable, then the result is ok.

I've created a test scenario to explain my problem:

I have two test tables:

Table: "Test Object"

[image]

Table: "Test Group"

[image]

These have a unidirectional relation on "Group code"

[image]

I have created a measure "Test measure":

[image]

This gives the correct result:

[image]

I have set a page filter to only show Group Code "G01".

This all works ok up to this point.

But it goes wrong when I use an IF function:

[image]

I then get the following (incorrect) result. Apparently the relation and/or page filter seems to be ignored now:

[image]

NB: The result is the same regardless of from which table I use the "Group code" field.

What am I missing here?

I've created a PBIX file that shows the problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/76ld1kv503ul6nm/DAX%20problem%20with%20IF.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Auto-Exist" in PBI:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/

If you look closer to the results, you'll notice that your report shows all possible combinations between Group Codes and Object Codes.

This is happening whenever you use a combination of fields from the different tables in a report: PBI first creates a cross-join between these fields, and then eliminates those combinations that result in blanks, so you only see meaningful combinations.

However, you IF statement overrides this logic - you are returning a result always, even if a combination is blank (Blank < 40 test returns "low end" because blank is treated as zero).

To fix it, calculate results only if the variable is not blank, i.e:

```
Price category = 
    var lowestPrice = MIN(Object[Price])
    var result = IF( NOT ISBLANK(lowestPrice),  IF(lowestPrice < 40, "Low end", "High end"))
Return result
```

You will get:

[image]

P.S. Page filter is irrelevant here, it simply filters the table **after** it's calculated.

Comment: Thank you; it works now. I'm still trying to find the logic here though. If I use lowestPrice in RETURN it correctly displays 10. In my logic IF doesn't need to calculate anything; just taking the result in lowestPrice ...

I'm going to test and study with your article. I guess the logic will come to me then ;)

Comment: I've read the article and somehow think I get the reason why it doesn't work. But I don't agreed with the article when it claims it's not a bug. It's a bug if it doesn't work from a user's perspective. I don't care how PBI internally works and/or optimizes queries. I thank you for helping me fix this, but for me it's a hack. Not a logical solutions. It worries me that I can encounter other unlogical problems like this one ....